# I can't use or find the google debian unstable/sid repository

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to use the debian unstable/sid branch of the google repositories: `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ unstable non-free main`, but I get errors:

```
Err "http://dl.google.com" unstable/non-free i386 Packages  
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.85.146.93 80]  
Err "http://dl.google.com" unstable/main i386 Packages  
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.85.146.93 80]  
W: Failed to fetch "http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/unstable/non-free binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 209.85.146.93 80]  
W: Failed to fetch "http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/unstable/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 209.85.146.93 80]
```

I get the same errors for `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ sid non-free main`.

I can't browse the repository at `http://dl.google.com`, I just get a 404.

Is it ok to use the stable repository instead even though I'm using debian unstable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes : stable here means "the stable branch of Google's repo" not "packages for Debian Stable".